# Is it possible to copy a web server?

Tags: upgrade, webserver

As of late my trusty old VPS (12.04LTS) has become slower and slower to the point where it's now completely unresponsive. I'm probably much at fault here as I've upgraded and installed packages without much thought.

I'm thinking I should start fresh with a new 14.04 install, I would however like to keep the web server portion of my current VPS. It's set up with multiple websites, some which rely on a MySQL server also installed on the same VPS.

My current plan is to simply copy my `/etc/apache2/*` and `/srv/www/*`. I think that part should be straightforward (or?). However I am a bit unsure if I can copy the MySQL server in the same manner? I'm hoping to avoid doing a dump of all my databases one by one (there is quite a few).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think just copy/pasting the files containing the databases would work well. Your best option would be dumping the databases in .sql files and then restoring them when you install the system. It could be easily done with a web interface like `phpmyadmin`.

Also, when you copy the apache2 and `/srv/www` you may have to restore the privileges and owner (usually, files under www belong to `www-data` user and group).

Another thing, if you're going to do a fresh install, make sure you create separated partitions for `/srv/www` or `/var/www` (in the latest version, files are stored under `/var/www/html`)so the next time you can do an clean upgrade or even install without losing  your server files.

Comment: As I feared then. Thanks for the tip about separate partitions though, will definitely do that.